# ggplot2 with ggmap odd shaped polygon R

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial, shapefile

I'm trying to plot a polygon shapefile with ggplot2 and I'm getting some odd results. I use the following code to read in the shapefile with a single polygon:

`zctaSp<-readShapePoly("zctaSp.shp")`

Then I plot using a couple of different approaches two of which work, but the one I need does not.

**PLOT 1: The shape looks correct with this:**

```
plot(zctaSp)
```

[image: plot1]

**PLOT 2: The shape also looks correct with this which seems nearly identical to plot 2:**

```
ggplot(data=zctaSp, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + geom_polygon()
```

[image: plot2]

**PLOT 3: But the shape is mangled using this:**

```
ggplot(data=zctaSp, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + geom_polygon()    
atl <- qmap('atlanta', zoom=11, color="bw")
atl + geom_polygon(data=zctaSp, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), alpha=1)
```

[image: plot3]

I put the shapefile at http://bit.ly/1nnlAg3.

Note that I did also try doing the plotting after running the `fortify` command along the lines of Hadley Wickham's instructions at [this link](http://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles) and this did not improve things.

Comment: Thanks for adding the graphics rcs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
library(ggmap)
library(rgdal)
# Data using NAD83 - epsg: 4269
zct <- readOGR(dsn = 'D:/Programacao/R/Stackoverflow/22387624',
               layer = 'zctaSp')
zctdf <- fortify(zct)

# Project to wgs84
wgs84proj <- CRS('+init=epsg:4326')
zct_g <- spTransform(zct, wgs84proj)
zctgdf <- fortify(zct_g)
map_loc <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(zctgdf$lon), mean(zctgdf$lat)),
                   source = 'google', zoom = 11)
map <- ggmap(map_loc, extent = 'device')
map + 
  geom_polygon(data=zctgdf, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), alpha=.8)
```

[image: ggmap]

A map from Qgis

[image]

Regarding the projections used in this exercise,the NAD 83 / WGS84 may be a pitfall. There are slightly differences between NAD83 and WGS84. NAD83 rely on GRS80 datum, which have a realization quite similar to WGS84 but not the same.

For these ggmap's one should always use unprojected WGS84 (epsg4326).

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! In playing with your code, it's not a projection issue because if you leave off all of your projection code what you have works. The piece of code that makes all the difference is the location specification. In your code if you use: `get_map(location = c(lon = mean(zctgdf$lon), mean(zctgdf$lat)))` it works perfectly. **BUT** if you use get_map(location = 'Atlanta') the polygon gets mangled. Your response was very helpful, thank you!

Comment: It appears that is related to polygons on the edge of the plot! Try, for example `get_map(location=c(lon=-84.42798, lat=33.749), source='google', zoom=11)`. Then replace the lon value with -84.48798. You will see that if part of the poly is off the plot, the poly gets mangled.

Comment: @user2631089. yes, ggmap cuts off the coordinates falling out the window producing that plot behavior. In my opinion that behavior should be avoided or a warning should be produced. Regarding the projection, be aware that NAD83 and WGS84 are NOT the same.

Comment: Agreed Paulo, thanks for the help. Yes NAD83 and WGS84 are not the same (though they are extremely (!) close and nearly indistinguishable in most contexts).